# Mafia 2 save game won't load because it requires DLC I've never owned (XBox One, Games With Gold)

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, backwards-compatibility, mafia-2

Years ago, I purchased Mafia 2 for XBox 360 through Games with Gold. In the last year, I started playing Mafia 2 on my XBox One X which was now playable through backward compatibility. I played off and on for several months.

This week, I attempted to load my save game and was told I couldn't load the save without installing DLC content that I've never owned. The XBox website says that I don't own any Mafia 2 DLC. I don't understand how this could have happened. When I try to load the DLC that the save game error message says that the save game requires, I'm told I need to purchase the DLC. This seems totally wrong. If I ever owned the DLC, why wouldn't the Microsoft Store or XBox Marketplace show it as owned? What can I do?